# RecyclerView item views are duplicating or repeating on a single viewholder as well

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler view that is adapted by Firebase Recycler adapter and whenever I scroll those items views in Recycler view are duplicating some views are getting on top some views are being in the middle.

I have tried every possible solution but nothing is really working.

Here is the Code.

```
public class MessageAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatModel, MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

    String SenderRoom;
    Context context;
    String ReceiverUid;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    public MessageAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatModel> options, Context context, String senderRoom, String receiverUid) {
        super(options);
        this.context = context;
        this.SenderRoom = senderRoom;
        this.ReceiverUid = receiverUid;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ChatModel model) {

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String uid = firebaseAuth.getUid();


        if (Objects.equals(uid, model.getSenderId())) {
            holder.messageBinding.senderName.setText("Me");
        } else {
            holder.messageBinding.message.setText(model.getNickname());
        }

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Users").child(model.getSenderId())
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String ImageUrl = snapshot.child("profileImage").getValue(String.class);

                        Glide.with(context)
                                .load(ImageUrl)
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                                .into(holder.messageBinding.senderProfileChat);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

        holder.messageBinding.sentTime.setText(model.getTimeStamp());

        if (model.getMessage().equals("Photo") || model.getMessage().equals("Meme")) {


            holder.messageBinding.SentImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.messageBinding.message.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Glide.with(context).load(model.getImageUrl())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .into(holder.messageBinding.SentImageView);

        } else if(model.getMessage().equals("voice")){
            holder.messageBinding.play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             holder.messageBinding.playVoice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             holder.messageBinding.message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.messageBinding.message.setText(model.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        SentMessageBinding sentMessageBinding = SentMessageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
        return new MessageViewHolder(sentMessageBinding);
    }

    public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        SentMessageBinding messageBinding;

        public MessageViewHolder(SentMessageBinding sentMessageBinding) {
            super(sentMessageBinding.getRoot());
            this.messageBinding = sentMessageBinding;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you until you provide us code.

Comment: i just posted the code have a look at once @VishalBeep

Comment: you should not add value event listener in a viewholder's onBind method because it will be added for every bind call so you will be adding multiple value event listeners.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @NikhilJain but the problem don't lie there its in the Photo ,Meme and voice message condition in if else, those views are repeating. Have a look at it once please!

Comment: The problem is that you are using a Recycler View.
Let's say you have 1000 items in the List object but the RecyclerView items only show 10 at a time.

In first load, 1 - 10 items are loaded to the all placeholders. 
And after you scroll, item 11 is shown but it will recycle the view, let's say the 10th placeholder.

When the data is set, the placeholder already contains other item data in. (i.e., not null, not default).

Comment: So you shall consider @NikhilJain concern. I am not sure that whether multiple register listener for same id in Firebase will cause any problem.

For simple rendering case, if item 0 have this condition "Objects.equals(uid, model.getSenderId())" == true and item 11 have this condition == false, when you scroll to item 11 and item 11 reuse the item 0  placeholder, you will have both holder.messageBinding.senderName.setText("Me"); and holder.messageBinding.message.setText(model.getNickname()); run

Comment: @AndroidNewbieA my problems comes this part. This section of code is repeating views  if(model.getMessage().equals("Photo") || model.getMessage().equals("Meme"))

Comment: The simplest fix is to reset your view before you start rendering it due to the holder will be reused. Set all of your holder view visibility to GONE or INVISIBLE at the beginning of the onBindViewHolder() call.

Comment: Just one more example to explain, For item 0, a placeholder decides to set "holder.messageBinding.play" to View.VISIBLE. The view will be rendered in that placeholder forever. Even if you recycle it unintentionally and use it for another item (e.g., item 11), the view will be visible if you don't hide it (or reset it) intentionally

Comment: @AndroidNewbieA is it possible to contact you once!